# Using flexbox grow but allow the content to overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, tailwind-css

I'm a bit new to using flexbox and I've ran into one problem I can't seem to fix.

#### What I want:

I want to have a container taking the available height, but whenever the content inside it takes up more space than the containers height, apply `overflow:scroll`

---

#### Context:

Ref image:
[container image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpQnL.png)

As you see on the image, everything inside of the red brackets are covered inside of a div with `flex-grow:1`, I want this because the images might be different sizes so therefore I need the div to take the reamining space.

As for the white container, that is also using `flex-grow:1` so that the button can be on the bottom of the div.

Now, what I would like is for the content inside of the blue brackets to be taking the available height, but if there is more content than the available height, then I want it to be scrollable.

The thing that happens now if I add a lot more content to the container inside of the blue brackets, it pushes everything below it further down, meaning the overflow isn't working.

E.g [Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVjfC.png)

As you see in the image, everything is just pushed further down and the div is being stretched.

Here is the code I have so far:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col grow overflow-y-auto w-3/4 my-2 mx-auto bg-white max-h-full">
                <!-- img -->
                <div>
                    <img [src]="currentUser.photoURL" class="w-full mx-auto">
                </div>
                <!-- information -->
                <div class="flex flex-col text-black grow">
                    <!-- Info -->
                    <div class="flex flex-col p-2 divide-y grow overflow-y-auto">
                        <div class="flex flex-col">
                            <p class="font-bold">{{currentUser.displayName}}</p>
                            <p class="font-thin">{{currentUser.email}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2 overflow-y-auto max-h-[90%]">
                            <div class="h-full grow-0 overflow-y-auto">
                                <p>
                                    some information about {{currentUser.displayName}}
                                </p>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        Some values are
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Some experience are...
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        Why im helping people...
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Message -->
                    <div class="shrink-0 p-2 text-center w-full bg-blue-500">
                        <button>Send melding</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I'm using tailwindCSS for this project, but will happily take suggestions in normal css as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution for this would be to set the div you want to be a scrollable as "display: block" (or at least some version of block) with a fixed height.  Once you apply that fixed height, your overflow content ought to be scrollable.

Comment: Kind of annoying that the solution was this simple, but thank you so much :) Been struggling with this for some hours now. You are right, just setting some fixed height on the overscroll div did the trick.

Comment: @MartinJohansen Awesome!  Glad that worked out for you!